# How to pass PHP value to Javascript and redirect to other page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Why is it that I cant pass a value from my PHP code to an OnClick function on my button to my javascript function depCheck2()? I would like to redirect it to 2 different pages depending on the value it carries. Could anyone please help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
$company_id = $_GET['cont']; 
$query = "SELECT count(Department_ID) as countDep FROM department WHERE Company_ID=$company_id";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);
?>
<script>
 function depCheck2(x){
     var CountRow = '<?php echo "$countDep";?>';
         if (CountRow>0){
             window.location.assign("editEvent.php?id="+x"");
         }
         else{
             window.location.assign("editEvent.php2?id="+x"");
         }
 } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("config.php");
$company_id = $_GET['cont'];
$query = "select * from event_details where Company_ID=".$company_id." ORDER BY EventDetails_ID DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
 echo "<table border=1 width='1000'>";  
 echo "<tr><th>Serial Number</th><th>Status</th><th>Event Type</th><th>Date of Event</th><th>End Date</th><th>Details</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    extract($row);          
    echo "
    <tr>
         <td align='center'>$EventDetails_ID</td>
         <td align='center'>$Status</td>
         <td align='center'>$EventType</td>
         <td align='center'>$StartDate</td>
         <td align='center'>$EndDate</td>
         <td align='center'>
         <input type='button' value='Details' class='btn btn-large btn-primary' onClick='depCheck2(\''.$EventDetails_ID.'\')'>
         </td>
    </tr>
    ";
    }
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a `$countDep` variable in your PHP ?

Comment: it came from SELECT count(Department_ID) as countDep

Comment: I believe your 'onClick' should be 'onclick'

Comment: you have error in `window.location.assign("editEvent.php?id="+x"");` replace it with `window.location.assign("editEvent.php?id="+x);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first: `<?php echo "$countDep";?>` contains `$countDep` which is not defined in PHP.

It is only present in the DB Query but you haven't assigned it to any variable from the `$result`

Then `window.location.assign("editEvent.php?id="+x"");` the syntax is wrong.

You have extra quotes at the end.

It should be `window.location.assign("editEvent.php?id="+x);`

Comment: Haha Thanks bro. IT Worked. I'm such a noob at this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
window.location.href ="editEvent.php2?id="+x;
```

Comment: Even window.location.assign("") can be used. Just that the user had extra quotes at the end. Also the variable $countDep was not defined anywhere